# Can't switch rendering engines

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

First off, I'm a beginner, and started yesterday at the time of writing this. I was working on a project (the donut) and when it was time to switch rendering engines, I switched to Cycles and it worked at first, but when I tried to switch to GPU rendering on my RTX 2070 Super, it reverted back to the look of Evee, but it still said Cycles. I switched back and forth a few times but it was identical no matter what engine I used. I restarted Blender, my PC, and I tried seeing if cycles would work in a fresh project (the cube only), but the same thing happened. I might try a reinstall, but I dont know if it'll work properly if I store the .Blender file elsewhere and reinstall then. Thanks to anyone that can help!
 - A confused beginner

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Does this happen when rendering? Or in the 3D viewport? Because viewport uses Eevee for *Material preview*, even when Cycles is selected for rendering.

Comment: please share more info, for example screenshot (https://imgur.com/upload) so we can understand what do you mean by "it reverted back to the look of Evee".. what does it mean? are you doing the render (F12 on keyboard)? what viewport shading are you working in?

Comment: Is this in render mode, or object/material mode? (hit shift+z until you don't see a wireframe to enter Rendered mode)

Comment: So sorry everyone, I just had the wrong viewport shading on! I feel like such an idiot... Glad to be a part of this community though, and thanks for the help!